# Server 2016 windows updates are downloading and installing. But the server is never rebooting to apply the updates

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

Server 2016 windows updates are downloading and installing. But the server is never rebooting to apply the updates.

Configure automatic updating: 4 - Auto download and schedule the install Install during automatic maintenance
Scheduled install day: 7 - Every Saturday Scheduled install time: 00:00 Every week Enabled First week of the month
Second week of the month
Third week of the month
Fourth week of the month
Install updates for other Microsoft products Disabled

Always automatically restart at the scheduled time is enabled for 15 mins

My understanding is Windows Update Orchestrator is in charge of scheduling the reboot. what does this task look like in windows scheduler? What log would I look at to see why it failed? The below says its scheduled, but days later still no reboot.

[image]

Comment: I ended up putting a GP policy to reboot the servers the next day. But I'd still love some insight into this.